# Searching for TeX Expressions using search system (ArXiv)

Tags: arxiv, search

I'm quite new to TeX - trying to use ArXiv's advanced search feature to search specific types of TeX formatting (I want to find uses of "small caps" in articles).

ArXiv supports searching "TeX expressions" with these instructions:

*TeX expressions can be searched, enclosed in single $ characters.*

### Link: https://arxiv.org/search/advanced

Thinking I can use the TeX code for 'small caps' formatting, I have tried searching using these, but they don't work, neither do variants without the brackets:

$\textsc{}$
$\sc{}$

I'm wondering if someone knows how to use this search?  I'm assuming I don't understand how to format a TeX expression?

Thank you in advance to posters!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best you can get, I believe, is searching titles and abstracts (excluding TeX expressions), simply by [using "textsc" as your search term](https://arxiv.org/search/?query=textsc&searchtype=all). This appears to work because arXiv does not actually render TeX in abstracts; it only marks math expressions for MathJax, leaving commands outside of math as they appear in the TeX source. There may be exceptions to this behavior, but I believe it is the best you can get.

If you want to search for text appearing anywhere in an article, you would have to use the full-text search (only available from the [simple search form](https://arxiv.org/search/)). However, it seems to be broken—I can't get it to work for a simple text search.

arXiv's TeX search appears to only search for exact matches of the text you put in—it does not allow you to search for partial TeX expressions. For example, there are [quite a few results for `$\mathbb{N}$`](https://arxiv.org/search/?query=%24%5Cmathbb%7BN%7D%24&searchtype=all), all of which include the blackboard-bold N as a standalone expression, and [no results at all for `$\mathbb$`](https://arxiv.org/search/?query=%24%5Cmathbb%24&searchtype=all). Similarly, [the results for `$x + 1$`](https://arxiv.org/search/?query=%24x+%2B+1%24&searchtype=all) do not overlap with [the results for `$x+1$`](https://arxiv.org/search/?query=%24x%2B1%24&searchtype=all).

Comment: Ok WOW you're good :)  Thank you so much!  This is actually perfect, searching abstractsis fine.  Looking for where authors 'name' something like a new method as they often use small caps for this, already evidenced by your test search.

*That said, wondering why 'textsc' works?  Think you're saying that when you use dollar delimiters $x$ it instructs the search engine to look for TeX expressions (as described), but in abstracts it just leaves the raw code there, so a search for that direct code actually shows the result, rather than telling it to look for rendered TeX that it won't find.

Comment: **So basically you can just type raw TeX code into the search and it should return those findings (from abstracts).  This happens to be exactly what I was looking for anyway!

***As it happens(!) I emailed ArXiv Help before posting here and their response was: "Only the full text pdf would be indexed, not the tex source (the tex expression engine is used to search for math functions in the metadata abstract)." 

Anyway this might be helpful to other people.  Thank you!!!